# Pandas replace an exponential values with constant for multiple coulmns

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, numpy, filter

Have csv file with some testing data and some columns have error value recorded. Want to replace error values like +/-9.900000e+37 in specific columns, name matches the pattern, with -9999.

I am using the following for now

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
df_1 = pd.read_csv('test_file.csv', sep='\t')    
df_1['Abc11'] = np.where(df_1['Abc11'] > 9999, -9999, df_1['Abc11'])
```

Having columns with that pattern like more than 50, is there a easy to update all column at once

Input:

| Abc11 | ABC12 | Abc13 | ABC14 | Abc15 | Abc16 | ABC16 | xyz | comments |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 13.3435 | -9.900000e+37 | 7.3214 | -9.900000e+37 | -9.900000e+37 | -9.900000e+37 | -9.900000e+37 | 0.3435 | Three |
| -9.900000e+37 | -9.900000e+37 | 98999999999999993400000000000000000000.000000 | -9.900000e+37 | -9.900000e+37 | -9.900000e+37 | -9.900000e+37 | 0.3435 | Three |
| 13.3435 | -9.900000e+37 | 7.3214 | 9.900000e+37 | -9.900000e+37 | -9.900000e+37 | 9.900000e+37 | 0.3435 | Three |
| 13.3435 | -9.900000e+37 | 98999999999999993400000000000000000000.000000 | 9.900000e+37 | -9.900000e+37 | -9.900000e+37 | 9.900000e+37 | 0.3435 | Three |
| 9.900000e+37 | -9.900000e+37 | 98999999999999993400000000000000000000.000000 | -9.900000e+37 | -9.900000e+37 | -9.900000e+37 | -9.900000e+37 | 0.3435 | Three |

if column name starts with ABC|Abc and values are > 9999 or < -9999 then replace with -9999

required output: no. of columns can be more than 50 with same name pattern

| Abc11 | ABC12 | Abc13 | ABC14 | Abc15 | Abc16 | ABC16 | xyz | comments |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 13.3435 | -9999 | 7.3214 | -9999 | -9999 | -9999 | -9999 | 0.3435 | Three |
| -9999 | -9999 | -9999 | -9999 | -9999 | -9999 | -9999 | 0.3435 | Three |
| 13.3435 | -9999 | 7.3214 | -9999 | -9999 | -9999 | -9999 | 0.3435 | Three |
| 13.3435 | -9999 | -9999 | -9999 | -9999 | -9999 | -9999 | 0.3435 | Three |
| -9999 | -9999 | -9999 | -9999 | -9999 | -9999 | -9999 | 0.3435 | Three |

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [`str.match`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.match.html) to find columns whose name starts with `abc` (in any case), then [`numpy.where`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.where.html) to set the out-of-range values to `-9999`:

```py
import numpy as np

abc_cols = df.columns[df.columns.str.match('^abc', case=False)]
df[abc_cols] = np.where(df[abc_cols].abs() > 9999, -9999, df[abc_cols])
```

Output:

```
      Abc11   ABC12      Abc13   ABC14   Abc15   Abc16   ABC16     xyz  comments
0    13.3435 -9999.0     7.3214 -9999.0 -9999.0 -9999.0 -9999.0  0.3435    Three
1 -9999.0000 -9999.0 -9999.0000 -9999.0 -9999.0 -9999.0 -9999.0  0.3435    Three
2    13.3435 -9999.0     7.3214 -9999.0 -9999.0 -9999.0 -9999.0  0.3435    Three
3    13.3435 -9999.0 -9999.0000 -9999.0 -9999.0 -9999.0 -9999.0  0.3435    Three
4 -9999.0000 -9999.0 -9999.0000 -9999.0 -9999.0 -9999.0 -9999.0  0.3435    Three
```

Answer (score 0):

This may help

```
df_1 = pd.read_csv('test_file.csv', sep='\t')

# Define the naming pattern
pattern = '^(ABC|Abc)\\d+$'

# Get the list of column names that match the pattern
matching_columns = [col for col in df_1.columns if pd.Series([col]).str.match(pattern).any()]

# Apply the replacement logic using applymap()
df_1[matching_columns] = df_1[matching_columns].applymap(lambda x: -9999 if (x > 9999 or x < -9999) else x)
```